# Replace double quotation to single quotation in R

Tags: r, mermaid, diagrammer

I'm trying to use https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/ to output some texts to a flowchart. This is the syntax I need to follow, which is a single quotation outside of a double quotation. For example,

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid('graph TB \n Trial_A["<b>Trial_A </b> 
        <br/> (BGL + PCD vars)
        <br/> (XAL)
        <br/> (RAX)
        <br/> (NOW)"] 
        \n style Trial_A fill:#FCFBFD \n ')
```

So I'm trying to combine a list of text using `paste0`, but it's always a double quotation outside:

```
textn <- c("This is a sentence [<b>]", '"a (panda bear)"')    
textn2 <- paste0(textn, collapse=" \n ")
textn2
"This is a sentence [<b>] \n \"a (panda bear)\""
```

I want

```
'This is a sentence [<b>] \n \"a (panda bear)\"'
```

Are there any ways I can do this? I tried `gsub("\"","\'", textn2)`, it only changed the double quotation inside.

Comment: Charlotte: when you type and run `'text'` in a console, you will see`[1] "text"`. because that is the output format for character vectors in R See what happens with `cat(textn2)`

Comment: also you can use `print(textn2, quote=FALSE)`

Comment: thanks @RicVillalba, looks like options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE); cat(sQuote(textn2), "\n") may work. I will test it more tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: `cat(sQuote(textn2), '\n')` beat any regex I tried.

Comment: A new issue comes up. When I do `cat(sQuote(textn2), "\n")`, the second string is on the second line because \n was there. I want the code to ignore \n and have this exact output 'This is a sentence [<b>] \n \"a (panda bear)\"' for the mermaid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noquote() is what you are after.

#### 1. See the input and output:

Run:
`noquote("Your text")`

You get:
`Your text`

### 2. Add single quotation marks:

Run:
`paste0("'", noquote("Your text"), "'")`

You get:
`"'Your text'"`

### 3. Re-use the noquote function again *(Sorry about the nested function - it's not pretty but it works)*:

Run:
`noquote(paste0("'", noquote("Your text"), "'"))`

You then get what you want:
`'Your text'`